Sqlite database does not getting passed properly from assets folder
I have this recurring problem that every time I run the main.dart and it fresh installs from the phone I am testing on, the database "chinook.db" with tables with data on it is getting passed to the app but there is no content in it. When I open the database in the data/data/com.example.(appname), it only shows "en_US" and nothing more. I can't see any fix on this everywhere. I will attach the main.dart and pubspec.yaml.
main.dart

Future<void> _openDatabase() async {
    try {
      // Get the path to the databases directory
      final databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      final path = join(databasesPath, 'chinook.db');

      // Check if the database exists
      final exists = await databaseExists(path);

      if (!exists) {
        // Copy the database from assets to the databases directory
        ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/chinook.db');
        List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
        await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
      }

      // Open the database
      _database = await openDatabase(path);
      setState(() {
        _isDatabaseConnected = true;
      });
      print('Connected to database');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error opening database: $e');
    }
  }

pubspec.yaml
  assets:
  - assets/chinook.db

I expect the database to be passed properly from assets folder to the data/data app folder. What I'm trying since I just started coding flutter a week ago and I can't see any fix to this is that I manually replace the database inside the data/data folder so I can test my app.

Have you checked the log? You might well see a trapped io exception (with a NOENT), as some versions of android don't actually have the databases folder. What you should do, if the the database doesn't exist, is to check to see if the parent (the databases folder) exists, if not (or even in any case) issue a mkdirs on the parent path. Then do the copy. The reason why you only get the locale (en_US) in the android_metadata table is that in the absence of a valid database the SQLiteOpenHelper will create an empty database.

I figured it out, I just haven't executed the copying of database asset on my login module.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
